# What does "another go at the thing" means?

Tags: meaning

In the British movie "*Pirate Radio*", Alistair family having dinner with Twatt:

> Alistair daughter: Would you like a mince pie?
>
> Twatt: Yes, l would. Thank you.
>
> Alistair: **Shall we have another go at the thing**?
>
> Twatt: Cracker, sir?
>
> Alistair: Yes, the cracker thing.

What does "another go at the thing" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means simply to try again or keep 'going' at it -- work at it until it is done.

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/have%20a%20go)

> Synonyms for have a go
>
> verb: try, attempt
>
> aim, assay, endeavor, labor, offer, seek, strive, struggle, test,
>   toil, travail, undertake, venture, work, have a crack, have a shot,
>   have at it, make a run at, put to the test, take a stab at, take a
>   whack at, take on, try out